# Edit binary data

Tags: python

I have a very simple problem which I am sure very easy to fix but I cannot yet figure it out. I have the binary files which has the header looks like this -

```
{
HeaderID       = EH:000001:000000:000000 ;
Image          = 1 ;
ByteOrder      = LowByteFirst ;
DataType       = SignedLong ;
Dim_1          = 981 ;
Dim_2          = 1043 ;
Size           = 4092732 ;
.....
```

What I want is to replace the data type from SignedLong to SignedInteger so that it can be readable by other software. So far I have tried the following code -

```
with open ('f0011.edf', 'r+b') as f:  
    f.seek(121)
    newbytes = 'Integer'
    f.write(newbytes)
```

The problem with the code is that it replaces the SignedLong to SignedInteger, but it also omit the ';' sign and brings the Dim_1 to the previous line which I don't want.

```
{
HeaderID       = EH:000001:000000:000000 ;
Image          = 1 ;
ByteOrder      = LowByteFirst ;
DataType       = SignedIntegerDim_1          = 981 ;
Dim_2          = 1043 ;
Size           = 4092732 ;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't do an "insert" operation on files. You need to rewrite it completely, probably fixing other header entries as everything shifts after you make the change.

Comment: I managed to solve it. Thanx for the tips.

Comment: If you have it solved you should post your solution as an answer and accept it so future visitors can see how you solved it.